# Can this integral be evaluated/approximated?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, contour-integration, approximate-integration

I've been trying to evaluate this integral without much success:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax}\,\,
\frac{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-c\sinh^{\,2}\,\left(bx\right)}}{\sinh^{2}\left(bx\right)}\,\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
I've tried contour integration. There are no poles, but I can't find a suitable contour such that all contributions other than that from the real line disappear.
If anyone can help with evaluating/ approximating this in the regime where $c$ is large, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason to believe that there is a closed form?

Comment: Not really. But it's the definite integral that I'm after. Any help in obtaining an approximate answer would also be very useful. 

this is what I can do: I can obtain a contour integral of $ \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, e^{iax} \frac{1- e^{-c\sinh^2 bz}}{\sinh^2 bz}$

Comment: then i would suggest that u also add the "asymtptotics" and or the "approximation" tag

Comment: ..with the rectangular contour :$ (-\infty, -i\pi/4)$ to $(\infty,-i\pi/4)$ to $(\infty, i\pi/4)$ to  $(-\infty, -i\pi/4)$ to $(-\infty, -i\pi/4)$. This is zero due to the absence of poles, and the contributions at $\pm \infty$ vanish. Also the integrals parallel to the real line are proportional. 
So I get : $ \displaystyle \int dz\, e^{iax} \frac{1- e^{-c\sinh^2 bz}}{\sinh^2 bz} = 0$ along the lines z=$(-\infty, \pm i\pi/4)$ to $(\infty, \pm i\pi/4)$. 

@tired: OK I will do that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Furthermore u could scale away one parameter. that makes things easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's begin by converting this to a simpler double integral:

$$\begin{align}b \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{i a x/b} \int_0^c du \, e^{-u \sinh^2{x}} &= b \int_0^c du \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{i a x/b} \, e^{-u \sinh^2{x}}\\ &=b \int_0^c du \, e^{u/2}\,\int_0^{\infty} dx \, \cos{\left (\frac{a x}{2 b} \right )} e^{-(u/2) \cosh{x}} \\ &= 2 b\int_0^{c/2} du \, e^{u} \, K_{i \frac{a}{2 b}} \left (u \right ) \end{align}$$

I turned to Mathematica for this integral, and it is a little ugly but could be worse as an exact representation of the integral:

> $$-b \operatorname{Re}{\left [2^{i a/b} c^{1-i a/(2 b)} \Gamma \left (-1-i \frac{a}{2 b} \right ) \, _2F_2 \left (\begin{array} \\ \frac12+i \frac{a}{2 b} & 1+i \frac{a}{2 b}\\2+i \frac{a}{2 b}&1+i \frac{a}{b} \end{array} ; c\right ) \right ]} $$

I did a numerical verification of this using $a=2$, $b=1$, and plotted against $c \in [0,1]$ and got indistinguishable plots.

Of course, we can debate whether this is truly a useful closed form.  Within Mathematica, the answer is clear - it sure is.  Mathematica can compute the closed form in a small fraction of the time it took to compute a numerical approximation to the integral (and it had a hard time doing so).

Comment: The nice thing is that ur integral is welled suited for an asymptotic analysis , because the asymptotics of bessel functions are well known :) (+1)

Comment: Of course, it would be nice if the OP could specify what approximation (s)he wants.  Is $a$ large?  Is $c$?  Or are they small?  Or is it $b$ that is restricted?  Hard to do asymptotic/approximations when we have no idea about the domains of our inputs.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar: Differentiating under the integral sign with respect to c.

Comment: Are you quite sure about the integration over x? because mathematica is not giving me anything on that one. 
Sorry, I should have specified the domain for approximation. $c$ is large.

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri: I am quite sure about that one.  Here's a ref: http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#i (#10.32.9).  For this, use the fact that $\cos{z} = \cosh{(i z)}$.  Besides, I checked the numerics before posting.

Comment: @RonGordon it seems that this reducible to a $_1F_1$ .